# Why VIEWS are showing in Data Transfer Service SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dts

Im trying to run DTS from one Db to another in Same server instance. But at the `select objects to copy` stage, its showing the VIEWs also. But VIEWS are only some customised queries. But why its been shows in DTS

Comment: Why are you trying to use DTS?

Comment: The reason is our systems team not allowing access to physical drives. so we are unable to take a backup and restore into another DB. So I thought about DTS..

Answer (score 3):

Either use the SSMS [Copy Database Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard)

Or use the SSMS Backup Database UI to backup and restore to the instance's default backup location.

Comment: The trouble as I mentioned in a comment above the system guys a crooks.. doesnt matter the seriousness or risk, they wont allow any physical folder to backup the DB. Also they created an empty Dev DB already and they are saying we just use that DB for duplication. So im getting option less.

Comment: Backup to Azure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url

Comment: You wont believe. In our network any kind of cloud storage, cloud notes, external emails are restricted

Answer (score 0):

If you are one of the dbas, and you need to back up databases, you need access to some storage.  If the system/network admins won't give you that, you have your manager go to theirs and get it resolved.  I smell a rat.

Also, to answer the question of why views are showing, it's because SQL Server shows views as if they were tables. You'll see tables and views when connecting to the database using most means. I am thankful for this, because it means my business analysts can tell me how they want the data to look, and I tell them the name of the dataset (view) they want to consume.